# Why LocalBroadcastManager of Android is not running?

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

I don't get what is wrong with this code.

The Listener is in the onCreate of the activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.e("MAIN onCreate: ", "It is never shown.");

        }
    };
}
```

The register is in the onResumen of the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("receiveMyService"));
}
```

The sender is in a button and I can see the Log is working perfectly, but with the value of test as false:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("receiveMyService");
        Boolean test = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.e("Button", "It works but test is always false: " + test);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Why the code of the BroadcastReceiver - onReceive never runs?

Comment: post complete code

Answer (score 1):

Because you register a `BroadcastReceiver` not a `LocalBroadcastReceiver`

replace this:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("receiveMyService"));
```

with this

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("receiveMyService"));
```